# Can Gurobi be used to solve SMT-LIB files?

Tags: z3, smt, gurobi

I have a problem that we were previously solving using a Mixed Integer Linear Program (MILP) and Gurobi. The problemspace involved roughly 200 million integer variables, with all but 5000 of them being zero, and 5000 (a very specific 5000) being a 1. The only arithmetic was addition.

Gurobi input files for this problem were typically 5-10GB in size (so big that I stored them compressed and developed a gurobi hack to let it read gzip-ed files). Gurobi could solve these problems in 60-600 seconds typically, but sometimes in 6000 seconds. Even 60,000. Never 600,000.

I have recoded the problem into SMT-LIB. The problems are now much smaller---just 100,000 integer variables. The functions used are now `ite` and `+` and `=` and `assert`. But on the versy simple problems, Z3 is taking roughly 10x-100x longer than Gurobi.

Is there any way to get Gurobi to process a SMT-LIB file?

**EDIT:** I am not optimizing, I am only interested in finding satisfying solutions.

As an aside, should I be looking at other solvers?

As a second aside, I suspect that changing the problem from 100,000,000 integers to 100,000 made the problem harder to solve. The mapping between the two problems is that the integer variable sin the big problem are clustered in groups of roughly 15,000, and in the small problem I instead have an 8-bit number, a 6-bit number, and two 1-bit numbers). Perhaps I should give Z3 the bigger problem?

Comment: Impossible to know without trying. Are you using z3’s optimizer? If so, it’s known to be much slower than the actual solver engine. You might want to directly solve, and then iterate to see if there’s a solution with a smaller cost. Surprisingly, that could be faster if the solution space is sufficiently small. If you are not using the optimizer, then I don’t see why you should expect z3 to beat Gurobi which seems to have custom algorithms.

Comment: Also, check out OptiMathSAT (http://optimathsat.disi.unitn.it/) which can read SMTLib and has a custom optimizer. It might perform well. Patrick Trentin (@PatrickTrentin) is an expert on SMT based optimization and MathSAT and does hang out here. He might be able to answer specific questions.

Comment: I am not optimizing. I would like to know if I can get Gurobi to read SMT-LIB files; it doesn't obviously support the format. It would be useful if I could transform a SMT-LIB file into a format the Gurobi will take.

Comment: I am not optimizing. I would like to know if I can get Gurobi to read SMT-LIB files; it doesn't obviously support the format. It would be useful if I could transform a SMT-LIB file into a format the Gurobi will take.

Comment: You might still want to try MathSAT (http://mathsat.fbk.eu/), since you already have the SMTLib available to see if it does any better. It's unlikely CVC4 or Yices will perform any better, but those are really your main choices. I've no idea if Gurobi can read SMTLib. It's usually not easy to get help regarding commercial tools on StackOverflow for obvious reasons.

Comment: Thanks. I intend to try as many as I can, but each one uses slightly different SMT-LIB vocab. I did my previous work with Sugar and picosat, but that only involved ~200 constraints. These problems involve >100,000 constraints. I am frustrated by the Gurobi solution because Gurobi is proprietary and because the LP files are so big. So I am investigating SMT-LIB.

Comment: Solvers do indeed differ in minor aspects, which is annoying. But if you find a solver not conforming to http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf then you should definitely report that as a bug to them! (Except for features they just do not support, of course.)

Comment: Also keep in mind MathSAT's license is not as friendly as z3's; if that's a concern.

Comment: If the logic used by your SMT-LIB formula is limited to QF_LIRA, then you may try [omt2mzn](https://github.com/cespio/omt2mzn), that translates  (a fragment of) SMT-LIB into MiniZinc. Then you can compile [libminizinc](https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc) from the sources with Gurobi in the PATH, so that you can then solve the MiniZinc model with Gurobi. As far as I remember, [omt2mzn](https://github.com/cespio/omt2mzn) should also have a simple support for **small** Bit-Vectors. In the case you are using Bit-Vectors instead of QF_LIRA, why is that?

Comment: If anyone is interested in having more information about the above solution, then you may read this [arXiv doc](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.01476).